# How to detect GPS satellite agreement is disagreed in android code

Tags: android, gps

The following screen displays after `Use location? dialog box` while using `goole play services` in android

[image]

I am using `SettingsApi` code https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi in android

I am able to bring the Use Location Dialog, but again another dialog appears for agreement to satellite GPS

How to detect if the user is pressing **Disagree** in this screen

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
    String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
   ...
}
```

See "[Requesting Permissions at Run Time](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)"